# pacmd is not working after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: pulseaudio, 19.10

After upgrade `19.04` -> `19.10` sound is working, `pavucontrol` is working,, but not `pacmd`:

```
$ pacmd
Daemon not responding.
```

I can see `pulseaudio` in the output of `ps`/`top`

```
$ ps ax -o cmd|grep pulse[a]
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
```

Why does it say `daemon not responding` and how to get pacmd working?

Comment: Check you logs for specific errors!

Comment: Use this command `sudo systemctl list-units | grep -i pacmd` to locate the name of the service file then use this command `sudo journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=<name_of_unit>` to see log entries for that daemon!